# Trying to update same column/table multiple databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to update the same table/column in multiple databases and get the 'must declare scalar value for @new_accountnumber for 3 of them.  Trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Code

```
DECLARE @Old_AccountNumber nvarchar(20)
DECLARE @New_AccountNumber nvarchar(20)
SET @Old_AccountNumber = ('TX000000')
SET @New_AccountNumber = ('ZZTX000000')

USE [HQDB]
UPDATE Customer
SET AccountNumber = @New_AccountNumber
WHERE AccountNumber = @Old_AccountNumber
GO

USE [HGSDB3]
UPDATE Customer
SET AccountNumber = @New_AccountNumber
WHERE AccountNumber = @Old_AccountNumber
GO

USE [Warehouse3]
UPDATE Customer
SET AccountNumber = @New_AccountNumber
WHERE AccountNumber = @Old_AccountNumber
GO

USE [Stationery]
UPDATE Customer
SET AccountNumber = @New_AccountNumber
WHERE AccountNumber = @Old_AccountNumber
GO
```

Error:

> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 14 
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@New_AccountNumber". 
>   Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 20 
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@New_AccountNumber". 
>   Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 26 
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@New_AccountNumber".

Comment: T-SQL variable scope is batch. After `GO` it is not visible. For multi-instance/database query processing I suggest [`Registered Servers`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/register-servers/create-a-new-registered-server-sql-server-management-studio?view=sql-server-2017) and [Execute Statements Against Multiple Servers Simultaneously](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/register-servers/execute-statements-against-multiple-servers-simultaneously?view=sql-server-2017). Write once - run  without repeating code.

Comment: [Please read about variable scope here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/variables-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) *"The scope of a variable lasts from the point it is declared until the end of the batch or stored procedure in which it is declared."* Your `GO` ends your batch, and your variable goes with it.

Answer (score 2):

Your `GO` Command is ending the scope of `update`  operation  or ending the declared variable scope. So, just remove `GO` command.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this a bit too if you want. You don't have to add a USE statement to access another database. Just fully qualify the reference to the table. You could do these updates like this.

```
DECLARE @Old_AccountNumber nvarchar(20)
DECLARE @New_AccountNumber nvarchar(20)
SET @Old_AccountNumber = ('TX000000')
SET @New_AccountNumber = ('ZZTX000000')

UPDATE HQDB.dbo.Customer
SET AccountNumber = @New_AccountNumber
WHERE AccountNumber = @Old_AccountNumber

UPDATE HGSDB3.dbo.Customer
SET AccountNumber = @New_AccountNumber
WHERE AccountNumber = @Old_AccountNumber

UPDATE Warehouse3.dbo.Customer
SET AccountNumber = @New_AccountNumber
WHERE AccountNumber = @Old_AccountNumber

UPDATE Stationery.dbo.Customer
SET AccountNumber = @New_AccountNumber
WHERE AccountNumber = @Old_AccountNumber
```